VBA delete row working in one for loop but not another
My goal is to have my program find all rows from a given table on sheet1 that either contain “Cancelled” in column AB or are not null in column Z and move them to sheet2, then delete them from sheet1. The first for loop (handling the “Cancelled” rows) works as intended. The second for loop however is throwing a run time error and saying “Delete method of range class failed”.
I tried removing only the myCell.EntireRow.Delete line from the loop and it worked fine (minus deleting the rows at the end). Why would this code succeed in the first loop but not in the second?
Sub move_rows_to_another_sheet_cust()
For Each myCell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(28).Cells
If myCell.Value = "Cancelled" Then
myCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
myCell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
For Each myCell In Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(26).Cells
If myCell.Value <> "" Then
myCell.EntireRow.Copy Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(3)(2)
myCell.EntireRow.Delete
End If
Next
End Sub


Why do you need the second loop?  You can have multiple conditions in your single if-statement.

It is always dangerous to delete things from a collection that you are looping over.  When you delete row 29, for example, what used to be row 30 is now row 29.  If it were me, I'd restart the loop every time I deleted a row.

I used multiple loops because they are each scanning different columns. Is there a better approach? @Cyril

A single loop could work such that:
Sub move_rows_to_another_sheet_cust()
    With Sheets(1)
        Dim lastRow as Long:  lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim rowNum as Long:  For rowNum = lastRow to 1 Step -1
            If .Cells(rowNum,28).Value = "Cancelled" Or .Cells(rowNum,26).Value <> "" Then
                .Rows(rowNum).Copy Sheets(2).Rows(Sheets(2).Cells(Sheets(2).Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row+1)
                .Rows(rowNum).Delete
            End If
        Next rowNum
    End With
End Sub


Accidentially left in i instead of rowNum in original post, so edited.  Assessing the individual cells in the column would allow you to avoid having a second loop.

Tried updated script, getting error "Row method of delete class failed" attributed to .Rows(rowNum).Delete

@KatBrown please make sure you grabbed the updated code.  I assume your error is due to the previous code listing i instead of rowNum, where i = 0 and that cannot be a row.

I am using the updated code, but noticing something odd. Despite throwing the error, if I let the code keep running in the background rather than ending or debugging, it actually works to do exactly what I want it to do, including the deletion. Have attempted multiple times and consistently works but immediately throws error. Any idea why this might be?

Also I mistyped the error, it's "Delete method of range class failed"

@KatBrown my first guess is you have merged data or it's part of a table/list, but cannot be certain without seeing the data.  In testing, this worked as is.  What is the rowNum value when the error throws?

rowNum is 1. Data in Sheet1 is within a table, is it a requirement that it isn't? Sheet1 is end user-facing and they need to be able to filter it.

@KatBrown change Dim rowNum as Long:  For rowNum = lastRow to 1 Step -1 to Dim rowNum as Long:  For rowNum = lastRow to 2 Step -1; it will skip your header row
